# Oracle resource busy error but v$locked_object is empty

Tags: oracle, ora-00054

I am trying to drop a schema but when i try to do it i get the ORA-00069 error telling me that the lock is disabled on myTable.
And if i try to enable it i get the ORA-00054 error resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified.

I tried to kill the sessions with no difference.
I checked in the v$locked_object table but it is empty.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in the table DBA_2PC_PENDING. There was a row there with the state 'prepared'.
I did execute: COMMIT FORCE 'local_tran_id'
Which changed the state to forced commit, releasing the resource.